# Validity of argument showing that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\rightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow0$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

I was wondering if the following step is valid:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\rightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow0
\end{equation*}
Since I'm saying
\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\rightarrow\sqrt{n}+0=\sqrt{n}
\end{equation*}
but not anything about $\sqrt{n}~~~(n\rightarrow\infty)$.
If it's not, is there a better way to do so?

Comment: The way you phrased it is not rigorous, but you do have the right idea. Try bounding your sequence above by a more familiar one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $$\sqrt{n}+\frac1{\sqrt{n}} \ge \sqrt{n} $$

We have $$\frac1{\sqrt{n}+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}} \le \frac1{\sqrt{n}} $$

Now you can use squeeze theorem.

Comment: As $1$ and $\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ are both positive, you also have $0\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}$. I know this is a trivial result, but I think it is worth mentioning.\ as you do need a lower bound to apply squeeze.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can't do that. If you take the limit, all $n$ have to be dropped and replaced with the correct limits. However, in your head you can use this two-step approach, but if you write it down it's only one step
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}} \to 0
$$
You can add for explanation that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \to 0$ and $\sqrt{n} \to \infty$. It depends where you need that, but usually you can use the fact that $\sqrt{n} \to \infty$ (otherwise you may have to show that as well).

Answer (score 0):

Your argument is valid, albeit not rigorous. Imagine it this way. The given expression evaluates to:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {\sqrt n}{n+1}$$
Which can be written as:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\sqrt n}{n} .\frac {n}{n+1}$$
Now, using algebra of limits:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\sqrt n}{n} .\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {n}{n+1}$$
First limit tends to 0 while the second limit tends to 1, so the net limit would be 0, clearly.

Comment: "$n+1$ can be replaced by $n$" That doesn't seem very rigorous. Perhaps try using bounding.

Comment: How about now? I formatted it properly and added the needed rigour

Comment: Now looks better.